# Using one responseXML over multiple HTML files?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking to make one XmlHttpRequest (every 30 minutes -- retrieving weather forecast) and use the XML response over multiple html documents. I've looked near and far and can only get the parsed XML to show on one document.

Is there a way to reference different documents from one javascript function?

No framework, just straight javascript/ajax.

```
forecastXMLreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
forecastXMLreq.open("GET",forecastURL,false);
forecastXMLreq.send(); 
forecastXML = forecastXMLreq.responseXML;
var day1 = forecastXML.getElementsByTagName("weekday_short")[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.getElementById("day1").innerHTML = day1.toUpperCase();
```

Multiple html files, one XHR call is what I'm looking for

Comment: You're trying to modify static html with javascript? Perhaps you can save the results of your request somewhere and then include it into html-files, but it still requires some server-side work (mod_include, for example).

Comment: What do you mean multiple html documents? You mean different html pages/page loads?

Comment: show us how you are retrieving the content in such a way you can only apply it to one page, so that we can see where your problem is and better give you an answer that applies to your application. Are you using any frameworks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to leverage regular http caching. On the next pages, you still need to request the file in your code, but the browser can potentially skip the request and just automatically and transparently fetch from the local disk cache instead. You aren't guaranteed it will be cached for the full 30 minutes, as the browser has a limited amount of cache space and it decides what to purge, and when.

Just configure the server to send the following http header for that xml response

```
Cache-Control: max-age=1800
```

more info on http caching
http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

An alternative is to make use of the limited support that browser offer for *html5 local storage*. No web server config is needed, although browser support is limited, and you don't need to re request the file in the code, but then again you will have different code for retrieving it from local storage.

Comment: HTML5 local storage. YES! Works. Thank you so much. I almost developed an aneurysm trying to research this.